# is the sentence God exists a logical statement?

Tags: logic

According to wikipedia a statement is either (a) a meaningful declarative sentence that is either true or false, or (b) that which a true or false declarative sentence asserts. Is the sentence God exists a statement? Me and some friend were discussing about the above sentence whether it is a statement or not. My answer to the question was No. Since its truth value depends on the personal opinions and so it can not be a logical statement( therefore different persons give different truth values based on their opinions. ) Please give a clear answer.

Thanks in advance.

Edit. Wikipedia says: Pegasus exists." is a statement is a subject of debate among philosophers. Bertrand Russell held that it is a (false) statement. Strawson held it is not a statement at all.
Is this sentence like the above one to decide whether it is a statement or not?

Comment: Nothing can be said about the statement until you define "God" and "exists".

Comment: Thank you very much Kenny Lau. Would you please give a detailed explanation in an answer if possible?

Comment: Item (a) a meaningful declarative sentence that is either true or false. "God exists" will be either true or false, according to the beliefs, but it will fall at the logical statement condition, right?

Comment: But when we decide about the truth value of a stement our answer must not depend on our opinion or beliefs as wikipedis says this.

Comment: My definition of “god” and yours may not (probably don’t) agree. So the statement is not, I think, well-formed.

Comment: @Lubin I think like you because of lack of an agreed upon definition of god.

Comment: God is the only one that knows all the possible theorems of mathelmatics. Let's agree on that definition of God.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your terms are defined, it is a statement.  It is either true or false.  (It can't be both true and false, and it can't be neither true nor false.)  It's truth value does NOT rely on opinions.  If God doesn't exist, no one's opinion is going to change that.  And vice versa.  It's similar to the statement "Sentient life exists on Epsilon Eridani b."  We all have opinions about that, but it's a statement because it's either true or false.  (Not both.  Not neither.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when we decide about the truth value of a stement our answer must not depend on our opinion or beliefs as wikipedis says this.

Comment: @Fermat and it won't. Either Christians or atheists (plus all other believers) have a wrong opinion on this either true or false fact. There is no ambiguity, other than that of defining the underlying concepts (e.g., is the God this statement is about the one described in the Bible? Or the one described in the Thora? Or the one described in the Qu'ran? Or the one described in Bruce Almighty? Or Shiva?

Comment: Your opinion is an opinion _about_ the answer.  It doesn't matter that you don't know the answer, only that the answer exists.  An example of a sentence which is not a statement is, "This statement is false."  This is neither true nor false.  Opinions don't cause truth.

Comment: What about the sentence "Pegasus exists " ?. Please read the edit that i added it to the question.

Comment: Again, you have to define "Pegasus", and you have to define "exists".

Comment: The debate among philosophers is whether we can talk about things which don't exist.  Some try to say that if the thing doesn't exist, then it can't be defined and so we can't talk about it.  Even smart people can get wound up in their own nonsense, I guess.  But the plain fact is, we have the sentence "There exists an odd perfect number."  The philosophy nutjobs would have it that this  is not a statement(?!)

Answer (score 1):

Provided you are clear about what the word "God" means, this is certainly a statement. Note that your opinion about whether the statement is true does not affect whether the statement is *actually* true - the planet Jupiter exists whether you believe it or not, and unicorns do not exist no matter how firmly you believe in them. The usual criterion for determining whether something is a statement is whether it can be *objectively* true or false - thus "broccoli is good" is not a logical statement, because it has no objective truth value; "broccoli is nutritious" is, because it is objectively true. Even things whose objective truth values are not known - for example, "there are infinitely many perfect numbers" - can be logical statements provided they *permit* an objective answer. "God exists" permits an objective answer, provided we agree on what we mean by "God" - either God exists, or he does not. A person's opinion has no bearing on the matter.

The reason that phrases like "Pegasus exists" are unclear is an issue of reference. For example, consider the sentence "The present king of France is bald." The phrase "the present king of France" clearly refers to a specific person, but there is no such person, so how can we say whether he is bald? Likewise, "Pegasus" refers to a specific individual, and there is no such individual - so "Pegasus has feathers" doesn't have an objective truth value, so why would "Pegasus exists"? In the case of "God exists", however, we aren't referring to a specific individual so much as an individual meeting certain conditions - it's more like saying "a deity exists", or perhaps "a deity with the properties described in the Bible exists" if you want the Christian God in particular. Likewise, "Pegasus exists" might not be a statement, but "a winged unicorn exists" certainly is!